# A check in C language if there is a space inside the array string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, space

How can I make a check if there is a space inside the array string? 
Could you help me? Thanks in advance ;)

```
for ( i = 0;  string[i] != '\0';  ++i )
        if ( string[i]) != ' ' )
```

> error: expected expression

Comment: Typo here `if( string[i]) != ' ' )` ==> `if( string[i] != ' ' )`

Comment: This `if ( string[i]) != ' ' )` has unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I think you should know that there are many kinds of "space" besides the actual space, for example tab and newline are both is considered space characters. You might want to check out [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace). And you need to think about how to handle multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: @Yellowfun Your Title say `A check in C language if there is a space inside the array string` and your code checks if there are not `if ( string[i] != ' ' )`. Make up your mind.

Comment: @Yellowfun Can't you see the extra `)` after `string[i]` ?

Comment: Jyothi Babu Araja I got it thank you!

Comment: you might want to use: `if( strchr( string, ' ') ) // then array contains a space.`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided an additional `)` in your if condition

```
if ( string[i]) != ' ' )
//here--------^
```

remove it or balance it with `(`

```
if (string[i] != ' ' )
//OR
if ((string[i]) != ' ' )
```

Always make sure to check for equal number of `(` and `)` in a program ;)

Since you wanted to check whether space is present in an array or not, you can do something like this:

```
for ( i = 0;  string[i] != '\0';  ++i )
    if (string[i] != ' ' )
       break;

if(string[i] != '\0')
    printf("space found at index no: %d", i);
```

If you want to know the total number of spaces present in the array, use a variable as counter and increment it whenever a `' '` is found:

```
int count = 0;

for ( i = 0;  string[i] != '\0';  ++i )
    if (string[i] != ' ' )
       count++
```

Comment: It is for my function that can count words in string.

Comment: generally, the number of words in a sentence are `number_of_spaces + 1`... hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you I've implemented that algorithm that you mentioned earlier and it works just fine. for ( i = 0;  string[i] != '\0';  ++i )
        if ( string[i] ==' ' )
            wordCount++;
        
    return wordCount +1;

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard function `strchr(string, ' ')` - return a non-NULL pointer if `string` has space inside:

```
if(strchr(string, ' '))
{
    // printf( "string contain space" );
}
```

Refer to `strchr` function:

> 7.24.5.2 The strchr function

```
     #include <string.h>
     char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

> 3 The strchr function returns a pointer to the located character, or a null pointer if the character does not occur in the string.

Comment: Worth to mention, in C zero is false and non-zero is true, so if strchr returns a valid pointer, it will be non-zero or true, and if it returns null pointer it will be zero or false.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my Comment there is a problem with the Title of your Question and with your provided code. Both are different things.

Your Code is OK if you remove an extra `)` located here:

```
if ( string[i]) != ' ' )
```

Try this Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    const char *string = "This is a String";
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for ( i = 0;  string[i] != '\0';  ++i ){
        if ( string[i] != ' ' ){
            count++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of Letters found are: %d\nNumber Of spaces Found are %d\n", count, (i - count));
}
```

Output:

```
Number of Letters found are: 13
Number Of spaces Found are 3
```

Comment: Also those `int`s should better be `size_t`s.

Comment: @alk You are right about that. I didn't do it because for this example int was enough.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "space".

The standard header `<ctype.h>` specifies a function `isspace()` which tests if its argument corresponds to whitespace in the current locale.    There are multiple characters for which `isspace()` can return true (e.g. in the C locale, which most english speakers will use, it returns true for the space character, newline, horizontal and vertical tabs, carriage return, and form feed).

If you want only a single character to be deemed a space, use `strchr()`.   If you want to specify a set of characters that are all considered whitespace, use `strpbrk()`.   Both of these functions care declared in `<string.h>`.

If you don't want to use those functions, then for whatever test you decide on for determining if a single character is a space, simply loop over all elements of the string, and test each one.  With "standard strings"  (like string literals, such as `"Hello there"` this means iterating until a character with value zero (`'\0'`) is found.

BTW:  the reason for the compiler error you mention is an extra `)` on the second line.